# No Warning with Raw Type

Tags: java, generics

I defined a parameterized interface:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public interface AbstractResource<S extends Parent> {

    Optional<S> getOption();
    Optional<S> getAbsent();
    Optional<S> getNull();
}
```

Then, I implemented it as a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Observe that I'm **breaking the interface** by returning the `Optional` types `Child`, `Object` and `Integer` for the respective methods.

```
public class FooResource implements AbstractResource { // Did not add type parameter

    @Override
    public Optional<Child> getOption() {   
        Child child = new Child("John");
        return Optional.of(child);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Object> getAbsent() { 
        return Optional.absent();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> getNull() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When compiling with the `-Xlint:unchecked` option, why doesn't the compiler show a warning that `FooResource` fails to add type parameters? In fact, it compiles successfully.

Comment: In Eclipse I get the expected warning: `AbstractResource is a raw type. References to generic type AbstractResource<S> should be parameterized.` Compiling with `-Xlint` also produces a warning.

Comment: That code alone won't give an exception, but the following assignment will: `AbstractResource<Child> abstractResource = new FooResource();`.  Although the implementation was caught in a warning, the original code was not. It's possible that, if this was a library, it would've made it's way into an library user's code-base.

Answer (score 2):

`-Xlint:unchecked` is for unchecked conversion (aka casts). It does nothing have to do with using raw types. Compile your classes with the option `-Xlint`. You then will get the expected output:

```
FooResource.java:3: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: AbstractResource
                AbstractResource
                ^
  missing type arguments for generic class AbstractResource<S>
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Parent declared in interface AbstractResource
1 warning
```

I would suggest using an IDE. Eclipse - for example - shows such warnings out of the box.

---

I just found out, that Java 7 supports more ["Xlint" options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings) (than Java 6, e.g.). So the option "-Xlint:rawtypes" will indeed help here.

Comment: Thanks. Besides these 2 javac options,  are there others that I can use to help me with generics?

Comment: @KevinMeredith See my edit. I found a link for Xlint options in Java 7.

Comment: hmm, compiling to `1.7`, I didn't see your warning with `-Xlint:rawtypes` and `-Xlint:unchecked` options

Comment: @KevinMeredith Are you using a tool to build the code or straight on the CL?

Comment: @JamesB - using Maven on the command-line with `<compilerArgs><arg>...`. Running `mvn` on debug, I see `... -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8 -Xlint:rawtypes -Xlint:unchecked`, which indicates to me that I've configured Maven correctly for those options.

Comment: Please try "-Xlint" first. That enables all warnings. If that works, "-Xlint:rawtypes" should also work. Otherwise ... strange.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - adding `-Xlint` alone did not produce a compile-time warning. Odd

Comment: @KevinMeredith That means, that the compiler did not get the argument. Maybe you placed it wrong. Consider James' answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the warning, you should be using

```
-Xlint:rawtypes
```

instead of

```
-Xlint:unchecked
```

For Maven builds, refer to this:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
   <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:rawtypes</compilerArgument> 
   </configuration> 
</plugin>
```